# Shorthand to set var = whichever is greater of 2 variables

Tags: php, syntax

I have 2 different possible values I use in an equation. I want to select whichever one exists and is greater using the least amount of code. It's possible neither variable exists, in which case year = 0, but one or both might exist. I.e:

```
if(isset($this->average['year'] || isset($this->Listings['year']) {
$year = whichever is greater of the above.
} else {
$year = 0;
}
```

It seems like there must be a shorter/ less messy way to do this than:

```
if (isset($this->average['year']) && ($this->average['year'] > $this->Listings['year']) {
   $year = $this->average['year'];
} elseif( isset($this->Listings['year'])) {
   $year = $this->Listings['year'];
} else {
  $year = 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`max`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and the ternary operator to do `isset` checks on both variables you can shorten it to this:

```
$year = max(array(
    isset($this->average['year']) ? $this->average['year'] : 0,
    isset($this->Listings['year']) ? $this->Listings['year'] : 0
));
```

Comment: Looks neat! Thanks - I'll try it.

Comment: In case it's not clear, the result will be `0` if neither are set. `max(array(0, 0))`

Comment: As John said in his vanished answer, it would be smart to write a method like `$this->getMaxYear()` to contain this logic.